# Assigning 6 "codes" to different ranges of values of a single variable

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have a variable to which I would like to apply specific codes accordingly:

Values 0 to 5 = "1"

Values 5 to 10 = "2"

Values 10 to 20 = "3"

Values >20 = "4"

Values 0 to -5) = "-1"

Values -5 to -10 = "-2"

Values -10 to -20 = "-3"

Values <-20 = "-4"

Here is a mock example of the variable of interest ("var"). Since I have it in a dataframe and one error message says something about "a condition having longitude", I put it in a dataframe here as well:

```
var=c(rep(1,3), rep(5,3), rep(10, 3), rep(20,3), rep(-1,3), rep(-5,3), rep(-10, 3), rep(-20,3))
var2=c(rep("long", 12), rep("short", 12))
df=data.frame(var, var2)
```

I have tried to solve this problem with the actual data I am dealing with through the ifelse function, but I only know how to apply it to three data classes.

```
var3=ifelse(df$var >= 20, 3, ifelse(df$var<10,1,2))
```

I have also tried another approach, the else if function:

```
df$var3=if (df$var < -20) 
{print("-4")}
else if (df$var < -10) 
{print("-3")}
else if (df$var < -5) 
{print("-2")}
else if (df$var < 0) 
{print("-1")}
else if (df$var > 0) 
{print("1")}
else if (df$var > 5) 
{print("2")}
else if (df$var > 10) 
{print("3")}
else (df$var > 20) 
{print("4")}
```

But the latter only throws up all sorts of errors. How can I best do what I want to do? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for `cut`

Comment: What happens if `var` is between 10 and 20, or between -10 and -20?

Comment: Good point, gonna fix it

Comment: Thank you @Sotos, I was trying to figure out the cut documentation, but I am a newbee, so understanding it is still a bit of a struggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sotos' mentioned in his comment, we can use `cut`:

```
eps <- 1e-10;
df$var3 <- cut(
    df$var,
    breaks = c(-Inf, -20 + eps, -10 + eps, -5 + eps, 0, 5 - eps, 10 - eps, 20 - eps, Inf),
    labels = c("-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "1", "2", "3", "4"))
#   var  var2 var3
#1    1  long    1
#2    1  long    1
#3    1  long    1
#4    5  long    2
#5    5  long    2
#6    5  long    2
#7   10  long    3
#8   10  long    3
#9   10  long    3
#10  20  long    4
#11  20  long    4
#12  20  long    4
#13  -1 short   -1
#14  -1 short   -1
#15  -1 short   -1
#16  -5 short   -2
#17  -5 short   -2
#18  -5 short   -2
#19 -10 short   -3
#20 -10 short   -3
#21 -10 short   -3
#22 -20 short   -4
#23 -20 short   -4
#24 -20 short   -4
```

Note that `var3` is a `character` vector (according to your problem statement); change to `numeric` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Mautis Evers, I was trying to figure out cut, but I am a newbee, so understanding the cut documentation is still a bit of a struggle.

Comment: You're welcome @Spaniel. I still find `cut` sometimes confusing; for example, if your `breaks` don't cover your data range, `cut` may put some numbers outside of the `breaks` range into an `NA` bin. Also, `cut` by default has an open-closed interval of the form `(a, b]`, meaning `a` is *not* included whereas `b` is. That's why I use `eps` to ensure that `5` is in fact included in interval  `(5 - eps, 10]`.

Comment: @Mautis Evers, you answered my next question before I asked it! Thanks again!

Comment: @Spaniel See my previous comment;-) `eps` ensures that `5` is inside interval `(5 - eps, 10]`. That's because the open-closed interval `(5, 10]` will *not* include `5`. Have a look at `?cut`.